# Is it always true that a subspace of a vector space is in direct sum with its orthogonal?

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space of dimension $n$ over the field $K$; and let $g:V\times V\to K$ be a non-degenerate scalar product (by ''scalar product'' I mean a symmetric bilinear map, not necessarily positive-definite), and $W$ a subspace of $V$. Define, as usual, $W^\perp = \{v\in V:g(v,w)=0\quad\text{for all}\ w\in W\}$. Then it is always true that $\dim W+\dim W^\perp =n$. But is it also true that $W+W^\perp=V$, i.e. $W\cap W^\perp=\emptyset$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a symmetric bilinear form can have isotropic vectors (nonzero vectors such that $g(v,v) = 0$) even if it is non-degenerate, and if it has, there are subspaces with $W\cap W^\perp \neq \{0\}$.

As a simple example, consider $g$ given by

$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$

The vectors $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are isotropic, we have $\langle (1,0)\rangle^\perp = \langle (1,0)\rangle$ here.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "the usual dot product", since that often refers to the sesquilinear inner product on $\mathbb{C}^n$. But with $x\cdot y = x_1y_1 + x_2y_2$ yes, you have $\operatorname{span} \{(1,i)\}^\perp = \operatorname{span} \{(1,i)\}$.

Comment: Oh, yes! So, for example, if I take $C^2$ as a complex vector space and the usual dot product, then $\operatorname{span} \{(1,i)\}=\operatorname{span} \{(1,i)\}^\perp$. Right?

Comment: Hehe, good that I didn't delete my reply ;) See above, @Matteo.

Comment: Ok,thanks for the answer!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm off to cook and eat now, so if you have further questions, the reply will be slower.